# text mode printing very light and font not changing php printer_set_option

Tags: php, thermal-printer

I am using a thermal printer for printing. when i use text mode the printer is printing very light and the font size and type also does not change. when I use RAW mode the complete string is not printed.

my code

```
<?php


header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$str="\n"."ItemName"."\t"."\t"."Qty"."\n"."Soup"."\t"."\t"."2";


$printer = "\\\\MON-PC\\Posiflex PP6800 Partial Cut"; 

$handle = printer_open($printer);
$font = printer_create_font("Arial", 72, 48, 400, false, false, false, 0);
printer_select_font($handle, $font);
//printer_set_option($handle,PRINTER_MODE,'text');

printer_write($handle,$str);
printer_close($handle);
?>
```

Comment: I can't even imagine how PHP can be related to thermal printer problems

Comment: its not printer problem

Comment: And yet there is a whole bunch of PHP and thermal printer related questions in the sidebar - a whole new world...